# how to do authentication in REST web service?

Tags: java, web-services, amazon-s3, restful-authentication

I want to know how to do authenticate for REST web service in java?
My supervisor want to get the format like amazon s3curl.
Everytime user request, they need to give id key and access key.
Which API should i used or for reference or sample code?

Comment: read up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454355/security-of-rest-authentication-schemes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon has an [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) that includes a sample S3 project, from which you could learn how they do authentication.