# What is the "realm" in basic authentication

Tags: http, basic-authentication, digest-authentication

I'm setting up basic authentication on a php site and found [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) page on the php manual showing the set up.  What does "realm" mean here in the header?

```
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
```

Is it the page page being requested?

Comment: I was bored by the fact that wikipedia page didn't mention about `realm` meaning and I was required to ask for that on SO. But then, luckily, your question appeared.

Answer (score 350, accepted):

[From RFC 1945 (HTTP/1.0)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1945#section-11) and [RFC 2617 (HTTP Authentication referenced by HTTP/1.1)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2617#page-3)

> The realm attribute (case-insensitive) is required for all
> authentication schemes which issue a challenge. The realm value
> (case-sensitive), in combination with the canonical root URL of the
> server being accessed, defines the protection space. These realms
> allow the protected resources on a server to be partitioned into a set
> of protection spaces, each with its own authentication scheme and/or
> authorization database. The realm value is a string, generally
> assigned by the origin server, which may have additional semantics
> specific to the authentication scheme.

In short, pages in the same realm should share credentials.  If your credentials work for a page with the realm *"My Realm"*, it should be assumed that the same username and password combination should work for another page with the same realm.

Comment: Some servers don't provide a realm in their authentication challenges.

Comment: When I work with IIS, I configure differnt realms for different virtual folders (under the same site). But I am not sure if this is correct. But it seems work for me. When I visit a virtual folder for a different realm, I did get prompt for credential.

Comment: Note:  RFC 2617 has been updated (NOT obsoleted) by [RFC 7235](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235)

Answer (score 135):

A realm can be seen as an area (not a particular page, it could be a group of pages) for which the credentials are used; this is also the string that will be shown when the browser pops up the login window, e.g.

> Please enter your username and password for `<realm name>`:

When the realm changes, the browser may show another popup window if it doesn't have credentials for that particular realm.

Comment: How to group pages under realm?

Comment: @Green The `.htaccess` goes by hierarchy, so anything that's under a certain directory can be given the same realm.

Comment: @Jack, I naively thought that all the pages with an authentication header with a given realm are in that realm and there are no other rules. Am I wrong?

Comment: Both Chrome and Firefox doesn't show the realm to a user anymore. I guess it's probably to avoid phishing attack when a hacker from evil.com makes a realm "Type your example.com password" and a user may not check a real domain and type it's password.
That's sad because it made the basic auth even less user friendly

Answer (score 27):

According to the [RFC 7235](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235), the `realm` parameter is reserved for defining **protection spaces** (set of pages or resources where credentials are required) and it's used by the authentication schemes to indicate a **scope of protection**.

For more details, see the quote below (the highlights are not present in the RFC):

> [**2.2.  Protection Space (Realm)**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-2.2)
>
> The "realm" authentication parameter is reserved for **use by
> authentication schemes that wish to indicate a scope of protection**.
>
> A protection space is defined by the canonical root URI (the scheme
> and authority components of the effective request URI)
> of the server being accessed, in combination with
> the realm value if present.  **These realms allow the protected
> resources on a server to be partitioned into a set of protection
> spaces, each with its own authentication scheme and/or authorization
> database.**  The realm value is a string, generally assigned by the
> origin server, that can have additional semantics specific to the
> authentication scheme.  Note that a response can have multiple
> challenges with the same auth-scheme but with different realms. [...]

---

<sub>**Note 1:** The framework for HTTP authentication is currently defined by the [RFC 7235](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235), which updates the [RFC 2617](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2617) and makes the [RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616) obsolete.</sub>

<sub>**Note 2:** The `realm` parameter is no longer always required on [challenges](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-4.1).</sub>