# how to make authorization to server into iOS app without user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apache, authorization

I'm new in `iOS` programming. I made `iOS` app with connection to `MSSQL`.

It works fine when online dialog authorization to server deactivated

Accordingly when we activate authorization my app does not work.
[Server authorization picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ1U1.jpg)

How can I specify authorization data in my app? 
How can I fill login and pass background in app?
And whether it be safe?

**My code is the next:**

## ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SBJson.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:msg
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];  
     [alertView show];
}

- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {
    NSInteger success = 0;
    @try {

    if([[self.txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        [self alertStatus:@"Please, enter login and password!" :@"Error" :0];
    } else {

    // login in app (this login is use for entrance to mssql base)

        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[self.txtUsername text],[self.txtPassword text]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://*****/file.php"];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: nil];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *urlData = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                            NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                            if(error == nil)
                                                            {
                                                                NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", text);

                                                                    NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                                                                              JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                                              error:&error];

                                                                    NSInteger *success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
                                                                    NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

                                                                    if(success == 1)
                                                                    {
                                                                        NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                                                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                                                                            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goto_login" sender:self];
                                                                        });

                                                                    } else {

                                                                        [self alertStatus:@"Login/password is wrong!" :@"Error" :0];
                                                                    }

                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                [self alertStatus:@"Connection error!" :@"Error!" :0];
                                                            }
                                                        }];

        [urlData resume];
    }
     }
     @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
         [self alertStatus:@"Incorrect login/password!" :@"Error!" :0];
     }
 }

- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title :(int) tag
{
     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                    message:msg
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     alertView.tag = tag;
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
         [alertView show];
     });
 }

 - (IBAction)backgroundClick:(id)sender {
     [self.txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
     [self.txtUsername resignFirstResponder];
 }

 // for login to server 
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
     if(challenge.previousFailureCount == 0)
    {
        NSString *user = @"*****";
        NSString *password = @"*****";
        NSURLCredentialPersistence persistence = NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession;


        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:user password:password persistence:persistence];

       completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: challenge.error = %@",__FUNCTION__, challenge.error);
       completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);
    }
 }

 @end
```

*And error is the next:*

```
2016-01-25 17:10:50.398 Report[751:22264] Response:<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fc691cf22c0> { URL: https://*****/file.php } { status code: 401, headers {
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 484;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
Date = "Mon, 25 Jan 2016 14:10:50 GMT";
Server = "Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)";
"Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm=\"Please enter login and pass for SOC\"";
 } } (null)
 2016-01-25 17:10:50.402 Report[751:22264] Response ==> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
 401 Authorization Required
```

*My php is next*

## file.php

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

mssql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mssql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

// Request type is check Login
 $password=$_POST["password"];
 $username=$_POST["username"];

// check for user

if (!empty($_POST)) {
  if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
  // Create some data that will be the JSON response 
          $response["success"] = 0;
          $response["message"] = "Enter login/pass!";         
          die(json_encode($response));
   }
   $query = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'and  password='$password'";   
   $sql1=mssql_query($query);
   $row = mssql_fetch_array($sql1);
  if (!empty($row)) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Authorization is successfull!";
        die(json_encode($response));
   }
  else{   
       $response["success"] = 0;
       $response["message"] = "Incorrect login/pass!";
   die(json_encode($response));
  }
  }
  else{ 
  $response["success"] = 0;
           $response["message"] = "Enter login/pass!";
  die(json_encode($response));
  } 
  mssql_close();
  ?>
?>
```

## db_config.php

```
<?php
 define('DB_USER', "****"); // db user
 define('DB_PASSWORD', "****"); // db password (mention your db password here)
 define('DB_DATABASE', "****"); // database name
 define('DB_SERVER', "****"); // db server
?>
```

## db_connect.php

```
<?php
class DB_CONNECT {
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }
    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
   }
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
        // Connecting to mssql database
        $con = mssql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mssql_error());
        // Selecing database
        $db = mssql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mssql_error()) or die(mssql_error());
        // returing connection cursor
         return $con;
    }
    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mssql_close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear

Comment: I don't know how to fill and transfer login and pass data to server background in app.

Comment: It depends on how you configure the server. Usually we use `Basic access authentication` which we put in the header

Comment: @YHaiti we made Basic access authentication but app doesn't work. I try to do NSURLSession with credentials but 401 still appears:(

Comment: @Maria can you share your code ? So we can see how do you use the NSURLSession

Comment: Thank you, @YHaiti.  I refreshed my question with code.

Comment: @Maria I suspect that the problem may come from your server configuration. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701085/what-is-the-realm-in-basic-authentication) may be you're in this case

Comment: Thank you, @YHaiti, we check. And is it normally that I transfer 2 different pairs login/pass: one for server and another for mssql?

Comment: @Maria what I usually do is sending only the user credentials and the server store mssql credentials and handle the database connection.

Comment: @YHaiti just we have different access level. For server it is common (only 1 or 2 login/pass for all users) and for database it is individual. May be I have incomplete php? I describe there only login/pass for database.

Comment: @Maria I can't tell if you have incomplete PHP, but I bet on that ^^

Comment: Thank you for help, @YHaiti! I add my php code to question.