# Does .NET HttpWebRequest Basic Auth / PreAuthenticate handle realm values?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-authentication, networkcredentials

I'm trying to call into a server that serves different [realm values for Basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701085/what-is-the-realm-in-basic-authentication) when accessing different sub-urls.

The client code I had so far didn't have to handle this, it just set credentials, set the `request.PreAuthenticate = true;` and everything worked fine for the communication:

```
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8877/" + suburl);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("User", "Pass");
    request.CookieContainer = cookies;
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;


        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            UseResponse(response);
        }
```

This automagically handles the inital 401 response and then transfers the credentials on each subsequent request.

What I do need to do now would be to somehow provide credentials based on the `realm` value that is returned in the `401 / WWW-Authenticate:` header.

Is there any built-in support for this in these classes or in the version using a [`CredentialsCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache(v=vs.110).aspx)? The [`NetworkCredential`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx) class only has user, pass, and domain properties.

The main problem I'm having with `PreAuthenticate` is that it is unclear what it is caching the credentials for - currently, from what I can see, I *assume* that it caches the credentials once per root URL (the Uri key of the `CredentialCache`), so there's no way `realm` can work with this, but maybe I'm misunderstanding something here ...

Comment: Adding the *realm* in the domain of a networkcredential didn't work?

Comment: @rene - I'm currently playing around with that. Not sure if/how this works.