# What is the purpose of the realm method in AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Looking at the (practically non-existent) documentation for `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer` I do not see any description for the `realm` method. What is it's purpose?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configurers/AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.html

I have seen it used in an example online in the following way, but without any description so I'm still not sure

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer
        .realm(RESOURCE_ID + "/client")
        .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
        .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
}
```

Comment: It is the realm for basic authentication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "realm" in basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701085/what-is-the-realm-in-basic-authentication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code of the realm method of [`AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configurers/AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.html) is:

```
public AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer realm(String realm) {
    this.realm = realm;
    return this;
}
```

The only goal of this method is to define the *realm* in the sense of the [HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-2.2):

> The "realm" authentication parameter is reserved for use by
> authentication schemes that wish to indicate a scope of protection. [...]  These realms allow the protected
> resources on a server to be partitioned into a set of protection spaces, each with its own authentication scheme and/or authorization
> database.

See also [What is the "realm" in basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701085/what-is-the-realm-in-basic-authentication)