# HTTP authentication without username

Tags: node.js, http, authentication

I am creating a HTTP Server in node js, and I want to add a password to a page that only I will use. The [Basic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Basic_authentication_scheme) authentication scheme requires username and password (In the browser popup). Having a username is useless for me and I want to know if its even possible to just show a password dialog.

The current code is this, sending a [Status Code 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) and the [WWW-Authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) header.

```
response.statusCode = 401;
response.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Requires Password"');
response.end();
```

Which creates this window in Firefox

[image: Authentication Window]

So what do I need to change in the response headers to only have a password field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to know if its even possible to just show a password dialog.

No. The [Basic authentication scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617) is based on the model that the client needs to authenticate itself with a *username* and a *password* for each protection space, frequently referred as [*realm*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35339784/1426227).

For a response with `401` and `WWW-Authenticate` with the value `Basic`, the browser will prompt for both username and password.

> So what do I need to change in the response headers to only have a password field?

If, for some reason, you don't want the username, you can leave it empty, pick a default one or choose another authentication scheme that suit your needs.