# Download file from URL in Python: only password - no username

Tags: python-3.x, http-authentication

I know similar questions have been answered extensively, but here is a slightly different one.

I usually do:

```
URL='some_url'
requests.get(URL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('userid','passwd'))
```

but now I am trying to download something from a website that requires only a password but no username. I have played around with None as userid but I still get <Response [403]>. Any ideas?

[image: password prompt here]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP authentication without username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580896/http-authentication-without-username)

Comment: Not at all. How are they related? Added more information above.

Comment: From the answer I linked: "The Basic authentication scheme is based on the model that the client needs to authenticate itself with a username and a password for each protection space." It seems that if you aren't prompted for a username this wouldn't be basic auth.

Comment: So what are you suggesting I do?

Comment: If you're trying to authenticate with basic authentication to a website that expects a different method of authentication, you'll have to figure out what the website expects. Maybe it expects the password as a parameter?

Comment: You'll need to post the specific website since each one has different security protocols. While it's 2020, not everyone uses standard OIDC tokes or an authorization provider.

Comment: Can you please post here how exactly you intend to check the security protocol of the website given its address?