# Should a Basic authentication request be POST or GET?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, basic-authentication, restful-authentication

I have seen Basic authentication being done in both `GET` and `POST` requests.

On the one hand, I suppose browser caching `GET` requests could be an issue, but on the other: `POST` is larger but encouraged for delivering sensitive information.

I am not asking the difference between `GET` and `POST` requests, but which one should be used for Basic authentication. Should `GET` be used only with HTTPS? Should `POST` be used always?

My question is which one should be used? Which one is a better practice?

Comment: A good Read:
[Which One is More Secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33837/get-vs-post-which-is-more-secure)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Should `GET` be used only with HTTPS? Should `POST` be used always?

HTTPS must be used regardless the HTTP method when sending/requesting sensitive information over the wire. HTTPS ensures that *both* body and headers are encrypted.

Bear in mind that sensitive information (such as passwords and payment card numbers) must never ever be sent in the URL: The requested URL may be logged by servers and proxies; If the URL is requested by a browser, the URL goes to the browser history. And then you have a security breach.

> Which one should be used for Basic authentication?

The [Basic](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617) authentication scheme is not tied to any particular HTTP method. Each [HTTP method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4) have their own semantics, so you may need different methods to design your API. And each of those methods may perform operations that require authentication and/or authorization.

The HTTP authentication framework, described in the [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235), defines that credentials should be sent in the [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header, so they can be applied to any HTTP(S) request.

It's also important to highlight that authentication schemes, such as Basic, are meant to be applied to *protection spaces*, often called *realms* (see my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35339784/1426227) for details).

Comment: you mean `Use HTTP(S) regardless` ?

Comment: @MOTIVECODEX Oh yeah! Fixed! Thanks :)

Comment: So basically, it's okay to use GET or POST for authentication request as long as you use HTTPS and the token is sent in the authorization header?

Answer (score 6):

Both GET and POST method is used to transfer data from client to server in HTTP protocol but Main difference between POST and GET method is that GET carries request parameter appended in URL string while POST carries request parameter in message body which makes it more secure way of transferring data from client to server in http protocol.
So it depends of your needs.
Hope it helps !

Comment: Can't you put the data in the body with a GET request if you want to as well?