# Private API for React (MERN)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, private, mern

I've been working on using the MERN Stack to build my web apps, and the only way that I have found to connect to Mongo is using an API. I want to make sure my users' information stays private. So how would I go about doing that? Is it possible? If not, how should I connect React to my database?

Thanks for reading, and I'm sorry for any unclear information. I'm new to this and don't know how to convey my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you are using the MEAN or the MERN stack. Authenticating APIs is pretty standard and for the most part, has been answered here on stackoverflow:

Please go to this link:

[REST API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999295/rest-api-authentication).

What you are looking to do is using the OAuth authentication standard. There are organizations that provide these services. [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#introduction) and [okta](https://developer.okta.com/documentation/) are examples.