# REST php webservice security

Tags: security, codeigniter, rest

I am building a **REST webservice** where the REST server is in **codeigniter**. The REST server is a codeigniter application which contains a seperate controller and model for webservice. What are the security issues in using REST? Also will it affect my application on security basis in using REST?

**Got a vague idea from these Stack overflow questions on Security of REST.**

[Security of REST authentication schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454355/security-of-rest-authentication-schemes?lq=1)

[Best Practices for securing a REST API / web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service)

Comment: You should check out Phil's work. https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver . All of the security are being handled by his library.