# Where exactly is REST authentication used?

Tags: rest, oauth, openid

I've been reading for hours, yet failed to find clear and understandable explanation. Where exactly is REST authentication used?

- Between browser and server (to replace something like PHP session/browser cookie combo)?
- Between server and another server?
- Between nodes/modules on the same server?

Let's say I'm developing a system from scratch and instead of having some monolith MVC on the server side I'd like to use twitter's example - make "all things REST" - system of distributed independent modules speaking to each other via REST. Can REST (authentication) then also be used between browser and server?

Comment: Most of the rest API's I've consumed perform authentication using tokens in the Authorization header of the HTTP request. That's of course if you're using HTTP for REST. This can be used between browser/server or server/server etc. Take a look here for a similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454355/security-of-rest-authentication-schemes

Comment: What do you mean by "REST authentication"? REST is an architectural style, not a protocol. There is no specific "REST authentication" protocol.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I understand what REST is. What I don't understand is where and how the authentication is used alongside it.

Comment: It's used anywhere you want to. There is no such thing as "REST Authentication".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to further improve behavior for Internet-scale requirements,
>   we add layered system constraints (Figure 5-7). As described in
>   Section 3.4.2, the layered system style allows an architecture to be
>   composed of hierarchical layers by constraining component behavior
>   such that each component cannot "see" beyond the immediate layer with
>   which they are interacting. By restricting knowledge of the system to
>   a single layer, we place a bound on the overall system complexity and
>   promote substrate independence. Layers can be used to encapsulate
>   legacy services and to protect new services from legacy clients,
>   simplifying components by moving infrequently used functionality to a
>   shared intermediary. Intermediaries can also be used to improve system
>   scalability by enabling load balancing of services across multiple
>   networks and processors.
>
> The primary disadvantage of layered systems is that they add overhead
>   and latency to the processing of data, reducing user-perceived
>   performance [32]. For a network-based system that supports cache
>   constraints, this can be offset by the benefits of shared caching at
>   intermediaries. Placing shared caches at the boundaries of an
>   organizational domain can result in significant performance benefits
>   [136]. Such layers also allow security policies to be enforced on data
>   crossing the organizational boundary, as is required by firewalls
>   [79].
>
> The combination of layered system and uniform interface constraints
>   induces architectural properties similar to those of the uniform
>   pipe-and-filter style (Section 3.2.2). Although REST interaction is
>   two-way, the large-grain data flows of hypermedia interaction can each
>   be processed like a data-flow network, with filter components
>   selectively applied to the data stream in order to transform the
>   content as it passes [26]. Within REST, intermediary components can
>   actively transform the content of messages because the messages are
>   self-descriptive and their semantics are visible to intermediaries.

You should really read the [layered system](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_6) part of the Fielding dissertation.

> Where exactly is REST authentication used?

It is used between a REST client and a REST service (the client sends requests - containing auth headers - to the service). A REST client can be on a browser, on another server, on your server (e.g. a load balancer), etc... It depends on the current context what is a REST client and what is a REST service. By REST you have a layer hierarchy in which the upper layer contains the clients which call the services of the next layer below, and so on... The components (clients, services) of this structure does not know of the existence of the layer hierarchy...

So for example it can happen, that a proxy relays the requests to the next layer without authorization, because authorization will be done by other components. It can happen that you authenticate your clients and add a secondary auth header with user identity, or permissions, so the layers below don't have to process username and password again. There are many options...

Just to talk about oauth. It is for authorizing access of 3rd party (non-trusted clients) to user accounts. So in that case the client runs on a different server, and it sends an access token (instead of username and password) registered by an user. This 3rd party client uses the allowed part of the permissions of that user. Many user can register the same 3rd party client with different access tokens ofc.

Answer (score 0):

REST is an architectural style and REST has nothing to with Authentication/Authorization.   That said, there are authentication/authorization mechanisms that provide a RESTFul APIs for REST style of consuming the services: [OpenID](http://openid.net/) and [OAuth/OAuth2](http://oauth.net/).  They are designed to used between client and server, and more (you can read more about them).

Also you may be interested in reading ['whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth)

Hope this help!