# Using Flask-Security to authenticate REST API

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-login, flask-security

I am using [Flask-Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) to build a web app that has a public REST API. I am trying to figure out how to add user registration and login using REST calls only.
It is fairly easy to create a user using `user_datastore.create_user`. But how can I then login the user, using a REST call?
If `flask_security.utils.login_user` took username+password or a token as an argument, it would be easy, but it takes a user object instead? 
The documentation shows how to register and login using forms and views, but I need to be able to register and login from an IOS device (using RESTkit).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Security of REST authentication schemes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454355/security-of-rest-authentication-schemes)

Comment: the examples seem quite simple. create a user, add the @login_required to your methods, then you can customize flask-login to suit your needs https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#login-using-authorization-header

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will either want to use [`flask_security.decorators.auth_token_required`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/api.html#flask_security.decorators.auth_token_required) along with `SECURITY_TOKEN_AUTHENTICATION_KEY` or `SECURITY_TOKEN_AUTHENTICATION_HEADER` (depending on whether you want to pass the token in the URL or in a header) or you can override [`flask_security.core.UserMixin.get_auth_token`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/api.html#flask_security.core.UserMixin.get_auth_token) for your `User` class and Flask-Security will do the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

[Writing an answer since I do not have enough credentials to comment on answer provided by Sean Vieira]

I looked a bit of Flask-Security code - it uses Flask-Login's LoginManager for this.
Flask-Login in turn expects the user to define token_loader (as well as implement get_auth_token in User class)

Does Flask-Security provide "default" token_loader functionality ? Otherwise - it is same as Flask-Login

Edit:
It turns out Flask-Security works just fine. I do not need to write my own token_loader.
I had security code in a separate file, and that is how "magic" broke.
I brought back the security code into myapp/**init**.py - and documented code "works"

Edit 2:
Refering to answer provided by Sean above. I don't think it is one or the other. One *must* use `auth_token_required` decorator. 
Overriding `get_auth_token` in `User` class is optional, in case you want different implementation for token generation (I think)
Overriding `get_auth_token` in `User` class is not sufficient.