# How to authenticate method on a web service so that hackers could not invoke methods within webservice using different tools?

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, webmethod, poster

We have developed web service(as well as generic handler)  based web application.But it seems that  the methods could be invoked by using different tools like (Poster,Advanced Rest Client) to get the secure information of Administrator and could do malicious activities.We would be grateful if you provide us the best possible method to make the method inside webservice or generic handler becomes secure.

Comment: Your web service is developed using what technology ?

Comment: our webservice is developed using asp.net technology.Please provide us solution if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is to probably know more about WS-Security in your respective technology

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security

Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms977327.aspx

Java: https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/

The above works if you expose as SOAP web service.

For REST web service, I found this link:

[Security of REST authentication schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454355/security-of-rest-authentication-schemes)