# How to design REST API for non-CRUD "commands" like activate and deactivate of a resource?

Tags: rest

Before I decided to ask this question I have searched quite a long for the answer but I haven't found any satisfactory. (e.g. [Examples of the best SOAP/REST/RPC web APIs? And why do you like them? And what's wrong with them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409338/examples-of-the-best-soap-rest-rpc-web-apis-and-why-do-you-like-them-and-what))

And the problem is actually quite simple. I have an object/resource named Account. My REST API supports all CRUDs with GET, POST, PUT and DELETE already with proper error handling, status codes etc.

Additionally however I want to expose an API ("command") to activate and deactivate selected Account resource.
Even if the "isActive" is a property of the Account I don't want to use just the Update from my CRUD of the whole Account.

I know it is easy to violate REST principles and make RPC style design with such design like this:

> PUT /api/account/:accountId/activate
>
> PUT /api/account/:accountId/deactivate

So what is the best solution for this use case?

My current idea is to use PUT and DELETE verbs like this (to treat it as a sub-resource) as proposed here http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#restful:

> PUT /api/account/:accountId/isActive // for activate
>
> DELETE /api/account/:accountId/isActive // for deactivate

What are your solutions?

Comment: I don't think that it's an "RPC" design. It's a "Message"-based design. Although, why not POST in the first example?

Comment: It seems to be standard to use POST as non-idempotent method. I'm still not sure what is the best design pattern for such "command" cases.

Comment: I found this interesting talk about "REST-Ful API Design" https://youtu.be/oG2rotiGr90 and use rules it defines e.g. PUT/PATCH for actions like "activate", "open", "install" and so on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about coming up with a noun for the feature you want to modify - 'status' in this instance. This would then become a sub resource of the parent entity. So for your case I would model the URI as follows:

```
/api/accounts/{accountId}/status
```

If the 'update' semantics are idempotent then PUT would be most appropriate, else that would need to be a POST (e.g if nonces are involved and are invalidated by the service). The actual payload would include a descriptor for the new state.

Note, I pluralized 'accounts' since you can have multiple of those, but status is singular since your account can have only one state.

Comment: Interesting approach. However in this way we will introduce something new from the functional point of view (a new property?), thus increase complexity. However, as I said gut point when designing the core domain model.

Comment: Its old thread but PUT "should" have body

Answer (score 5):

The POST method would create the resource 'account'. Active can be seen as one of the properties of the resource 'account'. Hence it should be a PUT request.

I would say even deactivate must be a PUT request as the account resource will still exist.

To activate an account you can set a property on the resource. That is:

```
/api/account/{accountId}?activate=true
```

To deactivate:

```
/api/account/{accountId}?activate=false
```

A GET request on the account would return a JSON with the activate value in it.

A DELETE request should completely delete the account resource.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this answer was down voted. I've seen this used before and it seemed appropriate.

Comment: Neerja, I think there is a reluctance to use query (?) parameters in this way, but instead to limit there use to selection criteria/filters.

Comment: We should limit query parameters to filtering

Comment: I don't think that's a good answer. Firstly, PUT should "replace all current representations of the target resource with the request payload" (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.1) which means you should PUT ALL the payload, not just single `status` field. You'd better suggest PATCH.

Comment: Secondly. "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, and TRACE methods are defined to be safe" (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) which means user does not have to care much about sending them - he should be assured that his actions with GET requests will not do any harm. Request with `?activate=false` params WILL do harm. In contrast, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE aren't safe and while user sending them he must think of he is responsible for any harm it'll do.

Comment: Thirdly, we may think of using `?activate=false` param with POST/PUT/PATCH, but it is a bad idea too. Here's a good explanation why we should not do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26717908/7744106 In short, "_query_ string does not (semantically) make sense" with the _post_ command (you're not querying data, you're posting it). Besides, POST requires `body`, so give it a body, not query params.

Comment: So I think this answer is good, but now it is out of date.

Answer (score 5):

PATCH is the most appropriate method in this case. Please find more at [RESTful URL for "Activate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790736/restful-url-for-activate)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it hides the semantic in the body of the request. I wouldn't do it even if it might be correct from the puristic  design point of view.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `PUT` is appropriate compared to `POST`, because you are creating a resource to an already-known location. And, I think, there's no dilemma about `DELETE`. So at first glance, your current approach seems to beat the alternatives.

I used to think the same way, until I implemented my own REST api, in which I wanted the admin to be able to set an account in a deactivated - yet not deleted, just "banned" - state. When I gave it a little more thought, I decided to do it *vice versa*.

Let me explain. I like to see the `activation` resource as "*the option to activate the account*". So if a url like `/account/foo/activation` exists, it could only mean that the account is not activated **and** the user has the right to activate it. If it doesn't exist, the account is either already activated **or** in a banned state.

Consequently, the only rational thing to do in order to activate the account is to try and `DELETE` the resource. And, in order to enable activation, an admin would have to `PUT` an activation resource.

Now, the question that comes to mind is *how do you distinguish a banned account from an already activated one*. But since a ban could be seen as a resource too, you could create a `/account/foo/ban` resource *collection*. In order to ban an account, probably for a fixed amount of time, you just `POST` a resource under that collection, containing all the details of the ban.