# Spring Data Rest/HATEOAS with Custom Methods Implementation

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

Considering [Custom implementations for Spring Data repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) I am using the `@RepositoryRestResource` on repository to bring all the HATEOAS generated goodnes:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends  PagingAndSortingRepository<PersonNode,Long>,
                                            PersonRepositoryCustom {


    List<PersonNode> findBySurname(@Param("0") String name);
}
```

Now following the mentioned docs I have created the `PersonRepositoryCustom` with additional, simple method for introductory purposes:

```
public interface PersonRepositoryCustom {

    public String printPerson(PersonNode personNode);
}
```

The implementation is:

```
public class PersonRepositoryImpl implements PersonRepositoryCustom{

    @Override
    public String printPerson(PersonNode personNode) {
        return "It Works!";
    }
}
```

I want the default SDR autogenerated endpoints to remain and just add the new custom methods/new implementations.
How am I supposed to use this custom method with spring-data Rest/HATEOAS? 
With simple `@RepositoryRestResource` the controller endpoints are autogenerated. What if I want to provide some custom methods? I presume I would have to create controller manually but how should it look like in this exemplary case?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, such a method on repository like `public String printPerson(PersonNode personNode)` is a RPC style API and it is a known anti-pattern, so you should design your API in a REST-compliant-way (see e.g. [How to design REST API for non-CRUD "commands" like activate and deactivate of a resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794744/how-to-design-rest-api-for-non-crud-commands-like-activate-and-deactivate-of-a))

The solution for your problem can looks as follows:

1. Create a custom `@RestController` (as you supposed) with defined `@RequestMapping`s for custom methods, which call relevant implementations.
2. Create a new `ResourceProcessor` for your entity and override its `process` method, adding a new link to the resource that points your custom methods like `/people/{id}/printPerson` or whatever your mapping definition is.

Here an example from my project (`Blog` entity needs to list its `Categories`):

```
@Component
public static class BlogResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<Blog>> {
    @Override
    public Resource<Blog> process(Resource<Blog> blogResource) {
        UriComponents uriComponents = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/blog/{id}/categories").buildAndExpand(Long.toString(blogResource.getContent().getId()));
        blogResource.add(new Link(uriComponents.toUriString(), "categories"));
        return blogResource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The custom method is added so you can use that in your code elsewhere where you would a PersonRepository. It doesn't magically map it to a REST operation, but the existing PagingAndSortingRepository mappings will remain.