# RESTful URL for "Activate"

Tags: api, rest, http, url

I have a resource (`project`) which can be activated and deactivated.
What's the most RESTful URL endpoint for this purpose?

Right now I'm thinking about `/projects/:id/activate` and `/projects/:id/deactivate`, but I don't think that's very RESTful.
In addition, I'm not certain what HTTP method to use.

Can you provide some pointers?
Thanks!

Comment: GitHub enables the API consumers to do this by a PUT request, documentation may be seen at [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#star-a-repository).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your can send your requests just to `projects/{id}` and use `PATCH` (as you're updating existing object) verb, e.g.

```
PATCH /projects/123

[
    { "op": "activate|deactivate", ... }
]
```

Read more: [REST API - PUT vs PATCH with real life examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459418/rest-api-put-vs-patch-with-real-life-examples)

Comment: I think I'll use `PATCH`, just because I'm already using `POST` for this resource and I don't want to have a huge route (using Node.js & Express). Thanks!

Comment: A small follow up question: what HTTP code to return if the project isn't ready to be activated?

Comment: `202 - Accepted`, which means "request has been accepted for processing, but processing is not completed yet"

Comment: That's good, but if I want to express to the client: "The project isn't ready because you haven't updated it yet"?

Answer (score 13):

The most conventional way to do this is via POST to /projects/:id, with parameters indicating whether you want to activate or deactivate or something else (always leave room for something else).

note that RESTful URLs should refer to things (like projects), not actions.  Then the common methods have clear meanings:

- PUT: create or replace the thing
- PATCH: set properties of the thing
- POST: perform an operation on the
  thing
- GET: retrieve the thing
- DELETE: delete the thing

Comment: Decided to go with `PATCH` for my own convenience. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 7):

I know I am a bit late but maybe this might be useful for others.

You can create a noun from your operation and use it as sub-resource: `activate -> activation`

Now you can use `POST` and `DELETE` on this sub-resource.

For example:

```
POST /projects/:id/activation       <-- activate project
DELETE /projects/:id/activation     <-- deleting the activation = deactivate
```

This pattern can work quite well for operations that toggle between on/off state of something.

Comment: We have also successfully used this in multiple APIs.

Comment: @MortenHaraldsen how do you manage PUT / POST without body ? (I think PUT is more appropriate as we are modifying state and its always will be idempotent )

Comment: @JigarShah - I do not understand the issue. There is no _requirement_ for a body when using any HTTP verb. The URL could carry all the needed information if need be.

Comment: @MortenHaraldsen https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT ...It says BODY is required. Its not that empty wont work. But its issue with tooling for example, OpenAPI spec expects body in PUT.

Comment: A content-length of 0 is allowed, which means empty body. I have not had any tooling issues with this. Consider an API that is touching (creating) a file with PUT. The file could be empty.

Comment: @JigarShah Also, OpenAPI 3.0 does not require a body: "Request bodies are optional by default. To mark the body as required, use required: true." - https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/